# Isomorphisms of causal structure of space with Lorentz form

Tags: affine-geometry, special-relativity

Let $E$ be a real vector space, and $q$ be a quadratic form on $E$ of signature $(-1,1,\cdots,1)$. Let us call **time** vectors the vectors $v$ such that $q(v) < 0$. The set of **time** vectors has two connected components. Let $C^+$ be one of them. It is a convex cone, and gives an order on $E$ given by: for all $v,w \in E$, $v \leq w$ if $w -v \in C^+$.

Every affine bijection of $E$ whose linear part is the composition of a homothety of positive coefficient and an isometry of $q$ is order-preserving.

Is the converse true?

That is, let $f : E \rightarrow E$ be a bijection that is order-preserving. Is $f$ an affine map of the above type? If not, what if we also assume that $f^{-1}$ is order-preserving too?

It looks like from a theorem of Malament [(click here)](https://doi.org/10.1063%2F1.523436) and a theorem of Hawking cited in the paper, assuming mild continuity conditions, such a map should be a diffeomorphism whose differential at any point is the product of a homothety and a linear map preserving the Lorentz form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the form $(x,y) \mapsto x y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, of signature $(1,-1)$.  The causal order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be the product order.

Any product of isomorphisms of the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$ will be an iso of the product order. So any map $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x), g(y))$, where $f$, $g$ are increasing (homeomorphsisms of $\mathbb{R}$).

Note that the automorphisms of the form $x y$ are
$(x,y) \mapsto ( t x , \frac{1}{t} y)$.

In this case it does not seem to imply the smoothness of the transform. Maybe in higher dimensions?

$\bf{Added}$ The answer is correct for Lorentz spaces of dimension $\ge 3$, cf the result of E.C. Zeeman, J. Math. Phys. 5, 490 (1964)

Comment: Sorry, wrote my comment too fast.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I agree that the causal order is the product order... I will then look more carefully at the theorems of Malament and Hawking. I am satisfied with your answer, but I'll wait a bit to see if you or someone have something to say about higher dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: @Plop: It seems some fine topology is involved. That topology was defined in a paper of Hawking et al.  "A new topology for curved space–time which incorporates the causal..."

Comment: @Plop  Found the paper of Zeeman where he proves it for Minkowski space E.C. Zeeman, J. Math. Phys. 5, 490 (1964)